# LibGdx Rendering images on a surface in 3D

Tags: eclipse, opengl-es, 3d, libgdx

How can I render an image on a surface in 3D environment? I know how to render 3D shapes and 2D sprites but how would I put a certain picture on one side of a cube/box for instance? or for instance I want to create a 2D square and put a picture on both sides of it then render the whole thing in my 3D environment. Or a box with different images on each side.  I dont know if I am making sense.

I am using libGdx on eclipse by the way.

Comment: Are you talking about things like bullet holes? Then you should have a look at `Decal`.

Comment: no not bullet holes. I'm not there yet haha . I think I am at walls . Like I wanna put up walls with different surface but I dont know how I would draw surfaces with images in 3D environment

Comment: Maybe http://blog.xoppa.com/basic-3d-using-libgdx-2/ would be a good introduction. It's called textures, not images. And you apply them to `Model`s using `Material`s.

Comment: I did read that tutorial but he doesn't exactly do what I am looking for. He doesn't applies textures onto his shape.

Answer (score 0):

I have some code like the following in my game. The wall is a simple box model that I generate in code. The texture is applied via a `Material`.

```
private static final ModelBuilder MODEL_BUILDER = new ModelBuilder();

public static Model createWall(float width, float height, float depth) {
    Texture texture = new Texture("wall.png");
    Material material = new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(texture), ColorAttribute.createSpecular(1, 1, 1, 1), FloatAttribute.createShininess(8f));
    long attributes = Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates;
    Model wall = MODEL_BUILDER.createBox(width, height, depth, material, attributes);

    return wall;
}
```

After that you can create a `ModelInstance` from that (`new ModelInstance(wallModel)`) and then render it via `ModelBatch`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I will try it now. How would I create a surface instead of a box though?

Comment: For a single surface you can use ModelBuilder.createRect(...)